# Sum of adding the elements of an array gives me the wrong output?

Tags: c, arrays, unix, shared-memory

I am using shared memory to add the elements of an array using two different child processes but the out put is not wrong. And i get a segmentation fault.

```
 int main()
{
int a[100],i,k,s1=0,s2=0,lim=100;
int status1,status2;
pid_t pid1,pid2;
int perm=S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO;
int fd=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,1024,IPC_CREAT|perm);
if(fd<0)
{
    printf("error");
    _exit(0);
}
 int* sum=(int*)shmat(fd,NULL,0);
if(*sum==-1)
{
    printf("error\n");  
    _exit(0);
}
*sum=0;

for(i=0;i<lim;i++)
{
a[i]=i;
    }


if((pid1=fork())==0)
{
    for(i=1;i<lim;i+=2)
    {
    s1 += a[i];
    }
    exit(s1);
}
else if((pid2=fork())==0)
{
    for(i=0;i<lim;i+=2)
    {
    s2+= a[i];
    }
    exit(s2);
}
else 
{
    printf("the elements of array are\n");
    for(i=0;i<lim;i++)
    printf("%d\t",a[i]);

    waitpid(pid1, &status1, 0);
    *sum = *sum+WEXITSTATUS(status1);
    waitpid(pid2, &status2, 0);
    *sum = *sum+ WEXITSTATUS(status2);

    printf("\nSum of all members of the array: %d\n", *sum);
}
return 0;
 }
```

This giver me the out put:Sum of all members of the array: 342
why?

Comment: What's the idea behind checking `if(*sum==1)`?

Comment: sorry that should be -1 not 1.

Comment: Even then, you need to check `sum`, not `*sum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a[10],i,k,s1=0,s2=0,lim=100;
```

and then

```
for(i=0;i<lim;i++)
{
    a[i]=i;
}
```

You're writing (and in the children reading) outside the array bounds, invoking undefined behaviour. Trying to explain the result further is pointless.

After that is fixed, you still don't get the correct result, the obvious candidate for the reason is that you try to transmit the partial sums per

```
exit(s1);
```

The specification for `exit()` in section 7.22.4.4 of the standard says:

> Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of status is zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned. If the value of status is `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is returned. **Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.**

One common thing is that only exit status in the range from 0 to 255 are used, and

```
Prelude> sum [1, 3 .. 99]
2500
Prelude> 2500 `mod` 256
196
Prelude> sum [0, 2 .. 99]
2450
Prelude> 2450 `mod` 256
146
Prelude> 196 + 146
342
```

your result is the sum of the remainders of the partial sums modulo 256.

Comment: even after changing it to a[100] it doesnt work.

Comment: yep found it thank you.